# Is there any ActiveResource like library for Java?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, rest, activeresource, inherited-resources

I know there are some ActiveResource **Client** libraries for Java, like [RAPA](http://code.google.com/p/rapa/) and [JactiveResource](http://jactiveresource.org/)

The question is: is there any easy way to create the **Server Side** of ActiveResource in Java?

In RubyOnRails all you need to do is to use the [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem. Is there any similar thing in Java?

Answer (score 2):

inherited resource only make your code DRY, nothing more. All magic makes Ruby on Rails.  If you ask how to do REST with JAVA like  Rails does than check this.

```
1) you can use JRuby and RoR together.
2) you can look at Groovy on Grails
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a specific library for creating RESTful webservices that implements what you need, I'm no ruby expert but it seems that active resource is something like active record but over REST, what I'd suggest you to do is use Jersey and ActiveJDBC together and maybe you'll get the flavor of it. If it's generic enough you can even make a framework out of it.

[Jersey Home Page](http://jersey.java.net/)

[AcrtiveJDBC Page](http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check out ActiveWeb: http://code.google.com/p/activeweb/, this is a Java framework inspired by RoR